# 'for each' not printing out list in PUG - please explain?

Tags: javascript, pug

I am trying to loop through an array passed by

```
res.render('index', { 'listItems': list_items });
```

Pug

```
  div#toDoList
    .col-1
      h2#user_name_heading=userName
      h2#user_date_signup_heading=userDate
      h2 Today's To-do List
      form#toDoList_form(method="POST" action="/")
        input(type='text' id="list_item" name='list_item' autofocus required placeholder="task")
        button(type='submit') ADD
    div.col-2
      .toDoListWrap
        ul
          script.
            each list in listItems 
              li=list
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

let users = [];
let list_items = ['jajajajaa'];



function addNewUser(data) {
  try {
    users.push(
      {
        "fname":data.fname,
        "list_name": data.list_name,
        "list_date": data.list_date
      }  
    );  
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Failed to add user ", e);
      throw e;
  }

}


/* GET home page. */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // check post valued are true
  if(req.body.fname && req.body.list_name && req.body.list_date) {
    try {
       addNewUser(req.body);
       console.log(res.headersSent);
       res.json({
         "message":"Successfully signed up!",
         "userName": req.body.fname,
         "userDate": req.body.list_date
        });
    } catch(e){
     // signup failed
      res.json(res.status(status).json(obj), "Sign up failed...");
    }
   }

   if(req.body.user && req.body.list_item) {
    list_items.push(req.body.list_item);
    console.log(list_items);

    // res.json({ "list_items":list_items});
    res.render('index', { 'listItems': list_items });
   }
});

module.exports = router;
```

console.log prints the following in index.js, proof there are elements in the list_items:

```
[ 'jajajajaa', 'f,ksha' ]
```

The browser logs this error:

> SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier

Comment: is this a snippet typo or the issue? "script."   - ie - there is a period after the script tag in the PUG

Comment: The period after script tells pug to output the content of that element as raw unprocessed output (see my Answer).  It is not needed for the purpose of rendering a list.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the `script.` tag.  That tells pug to output a `<script></script>` tag in the page and then output the raw content underneath it.

Just take the `script.` tag out and only this is needed in your template:

```
each list in listItems 
  li= list
```

This will loop as expected and create `<li>` elements for each entry in listItems.

Your posted code would output this:

```
<script>
  each list in listItems 
    li=list
</script>
```

And of course your browser can't understand pug code, that text is invalid as JavaScript.

I understand that by fixing this problem you are getting a new error.

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/graham-sportsmgmt/pen/mQKXBx) that replicates your template and it works fine for me.  This is the pug code:

```
- var listItems = [ 'jajajajaa', 'f,ksha' ];

ul
  each list in listItems 
    li= list
```

Let's now use the script tag to troubleshoot this secondary issue.  Add this code in your template in order to output the value of listItems to the browser console:

```
script.
  console.log(!{JSON.stringify(listItems)});
```

The `!{}` sequence outputs an unbuffered code expression.  The stringify will be rendered on the server into a valid JavaScript value and will test the value of listItems as it appears inside the pug template.

Comment: but if I remove it, I get this error on page: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined?

Comment: I promise you 100% that the script. tag is incorrect and is causing the first problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `console.log(list_items);` - that will help diagnose the second problem.

Comment: You're right, the issue is with my index.js and the array im sending in res.render()... it doesn't show any values in the list for some reason. Its a simple global list with a default value, yet nothing prints?

Comment: See codepen with sample code, it's working for me.  I'll add one more troubleshooting step into my answer.